# How to solve [object object] coming iin html using angular2

Tags: angular

I have response from API, I need to bind that to HTML. But getting [object,object].

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbyek9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="menu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu)">
 <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu}}</span>
```

TS:

This is the response got from API.

```
userMenu: any = [{
    HasCaseManagement: 1,
HasDicom: 1,
HasEMR: 1,
HasHomeDashboard: 1,
HasReport: 1,
HasSystemSettings: 1,
HasUserManagement: 1,
Id: 1
  }];
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to show in the span?

Comment: I need to display these values,HasCaseManagement: 1, HasDicom: 1, HasEMR: 1, HasHomeDashboard: 1, HasReport: 1, HasSystemSettings: 1, HasUserManagement: 1

Comment: @Bhrungarajni check my answer... its exact as per your requirement

Comment: This isn't supposed to be asked here, the answer could be easily be found with few minutes with  some Google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <ul class="metismenu" id="menu">
        <li class="m--5" *ngFor="let menu of userMenu">
            <a class="nav-link">
        <div *ngFor="let item of objectToArray(menu)">
          <input
            type="checkbox" 
            [checked]="item.value" 
            (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu.Id)">
          <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{item.key}}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And add this method in your Component Class:

```
objectToArray(object) {
  const keyValues = [];
  for (let key in object) {
    if (key !== 'Id') {
      const objectToPush = {
        key,
        value: object[key]
      };
      keyValues.push(objectToPush);
    }
  }
  return keyValues;
}
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgyugx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: i want this to display as items one below the other and Id should not display

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, I've updated my answer and the sample StackBlitz. Check if that helps.

Comment: ya this is fine, can we remove Id in this?

Comment: ya this is fine, thank you il vote answer. i need ur help

Comment: Here i have home dashboard, so i want that to be checked always and it must be disabled.. can that be done?

Comment: here in demo its working but not in my application, can you please help me where im wrong

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, I'd suggest you ask another question regarding that. That would help to keep this thread clean and focused. Also once you do ask the question, please provide relevant details regarding it.

Comment: ya sure il create one more question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186090/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-siddajmera).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="menu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu)">
<span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu | json}}</span>
```

Or if you want to access a particular value from json object :

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="menu.isChecked" (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, menu)">
    <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.HasCaseManagement}}</span>
    <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.HasDicom}}</span>
    <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.HasEMR}}</span> 
    <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{menu.HasReport}}</span>
```

Comment: no i want all items to be displayed as a list of items one below the other